# Need some help with a SQL query (SQL Server 2005) to transform this data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, transform

Here's a simplistic look at the table I have

## Category

- CategoryId
- CategoryName
- ParentCategoryId

As you can see, the catalog table is a self referencing table, so recursing it is possible by starting at 0, which is the fake "root" category (could just as well be null, but it's not).

Sample Data:

```
1, Apples, 0
5, Yummy, 1
10, Really Yummy, 5
15, Yucky, 0
18, Some Sub Cat, 15
20, Some Deep Sub Cat, 18
25, Some Deep Sub Cat 2, 18
```

The deepest any category hierarchy can be is 4 deep, and I'm trying to get an output that looks like this:

```
CatId, [up to 4 deep of category names on the hierarchy in separate columns, or null if none]
1, Apples, NULL, NULL, NULL
5, Apples, Yummy, NULL, NULL
10, Apples, Yummy, Really Yummy, NULL
15, Apples, Yucky, NULL, NULL
18, Apples, Yucky, Some Sub Cat, NULL
20, Apples, Yucky, Some Sub Cat, Some Deep Sub Cat
25, Apples, Yucky, Some Sub Cat, Some Deep Sub Cat 2
```

This SQL is close, but it generates it backwards, left justified

```
select c1.categoryid, c1.name, c2.name, c3.name, c4.name
from category c1
    left outer join category c2
        on c1.parentcategoryid = c2.categoryid
    left outer join category c3
        on c2.parentcategoryid = c3.categoryid
    left outer join category c4
        on c3.parentcategoryid = c4.categoryid
```

Any SQL geniuses have some good ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
select c1.CategoryId as id,
       c1.CategoryName as n1,
       c2.CategoryName as n2,
       c3.CategoryName as n3,
       c4.CategoryName as n4
from            Category c1
left outer join Category c2 on c2.ParentCategoryId = c1.CategoryId
left outer join Category c3 on c3.ParentCategoryId = c2.CategoryId
left outer join Category c4 on c4.ParentCategoryId = c3.CategoryId
where c1.parentcategoryid = 0;
```

(per your edit: you've just got ParentCategoryId and CategoryID flipped in the joins.)

Comment: Quite close...  A couple changes.  Needs a where clause "where c1.parentcategoryid = 0" or it prints bum results.  Then it needs a case statement maybe to determine the id to show (deepest level)?  Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks; I've added the WHERE clause you suggest.  I would avoid the CASE statement - I don't think SQL handles conditional flow logic of that sort very elegantly - and simply write the other three queries as desired.  I know some developers hate duplication enough to go to the trouble of writing and maintaining the case statement, but for me it's a better fit with the language.

Comment: then this is wrong, the categoryid printed is the root categoryid.  I needed to print the deepest level category.  The case statement worked fine.

Comment: This leaves out non-leaf categories